# Asp.Net Core - how to handle a service lifetime when the service is needed after the response returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, task

I´m developing a service, that receives a `HTTPPost` request.
That request should start a long running process - (seconds to minutes).

At the client side I don´t want to wait all the time for the response, so I build the workflow as following:

- client sends the request
- server starts the job to do and immediately returns a guid - the job id
- when the job completes on the server, it raises an event to inform the client about the completion (technically I use SignalR but that doesn´t matter)

A code sample:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class JobsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IJobService jobService;

    public JobsController(IJobService jobService)
    {
        this.jobService = jobService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jobService));
        jobService.JobCompleted += id =>
        {
            // inform the client somehow
        };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("newJob")]
    public IActionResult CreateNewJob(NewJob newJob)
    {
        var jobId = jobService.CreateNewJob(newJob);
        return Ok(jobId);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class JobService : IJobService
{
    private readonly IImportantService importantService;
    public event Action<string> JobCompleted;

    public JobService(IImportantService importantService)
        => this.importantService = importantService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(importantService));

    public string CreateNewJob(NewJob newJob)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("H");
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // do the long running operation
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            await importantService.DoSomethingAsync(newJob);   // here is the problem - this service is already disposed            

            JobCompleted?.Invoke(id);
        });
        return id;
    }
}
```

So the problem is, that I´m using the `importantService` in a `Task` that is running long after the request returned to the user.

But ASP.NET Core DI container is (normally) correctly disposing all services created for the request immediately.

How can I tell ASP.Net to not dispose `importantService` as long as the background task is  still running?

Or is it better to do a complete different way - thinking about [hangfire.io](https://www.hangfire.io/) or similar...

Thank you! :)

Comment: Can't you use a singleton implementation for the service? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#singleton

Comment: Yes I can use my that services as singleton - that´s a great and easy solution! Thank you! :D

Comment: You could also use a [HostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). Just add an entry to a queue on a incoming request and the HostedService will process the job and calls the client after finishing it. Imho is this a cleaner solution than just making your service a singleton.

Comment: @JakobFerdinand Because the `Task.Run` is not awaited, everything is going out of scope on the separate thread by the time you try to access the original object. It is exactly as you said. The request returns as soon as you invoke your function. Once the request completes, it disposes of everything created through the scope of that request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your service as a **singleton** [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#service-lifetimes) , that means it will keep alive throughout the application life cycle.